# Disable Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter Permanantly

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-configuration, virtual-wifi

Is there a simple and permanent way to disable the Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter permanently.

I believe this device may be the source of some wifi problems my users have been having.

Comment: This link was mentioned in another thread (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd759204.aspx). They say it worked. But I cannot figure out how to follow the steps.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

AFAIK, the Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter is a virtual adaptor for sharing your internet connection (ie. making a wifi hotspot, or 'hosted network').

To disable this, open an elevated command prompt (cmd as admin) and type in the following commands, in order:

`netsh wlan stop hostednetwork` This stops the hosted network

`netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=disallow` This disables the hotspot.

<sub>[Source for commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/dd815243%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)</sub>

This worked for me and removed the adaptor on my computer.

Comment: This works only temporarily. The Miniport Adapters reappear after some time (reboot?).

Comment: Shouldn't do - it never came back for me... @Alph.Dev :/

Comment: I ran these commantds 3 times already. Every time it works. But when I experience wifi problems I visit Control panel > Network connections, and yep, there they are again. 2 Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapters.

Comment: If you can see the adapters in Device Manager, can you delete them?

Comment: Deleting/Uninstalling these adapters in Device Manager works until reboot.

Comment: hmmm... sorry then @Alph.Dev I can't think of what could be the problem - it worked for me! Do you have any programs installed that are reinstalling/reenabling the adapter on reboot? How did you originally enable them?

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `netsh wlan show hostednetwork` will let you see if this feature is turned on in the first place.  If it is, then the `Mode:` will be set to `Allowed`.

Comment: @Alph.Dev, then you have some other software which re-enables it, just like `netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow` does. This is privileged operation to narrow suspects down

Answer (score 1):

To permanent deletion of the hosted network adapter (Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter) just delete in windows registers this key:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Wlansvc\Parameters\HostedNetworkSettings\HostedNetworkSettings`

Answer (score 0):

This virtual adapter was installed by my Intel Wireless driver software. I was unable to disconnect my main Network Interface Card driver from this virtual adapter software.  So I just disabled the virtual adapter from the network connections window.

```
Right-click->disable
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

look up device manager> view (on the top bar)> view hidden devices> network adapters(in the main area)> find microsoft virtual adapter> right click disable.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gg0To.png)

Answer (score -1):

nope u need to look up device manager>view hidden devices(at the top)> on the main screen under network adapter find the microsoft virtual adapters > right click disable

[image]